# JQuery - Mouseenter / hover event on top level menu ONLY, not the submenu ( list items NOT nested list items)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a navigation menu with 2 levels built using nested lists.  I need an event to only trigger on the mouseenter of the top level of the menu, not the submenu.  From what I have read this should work as it should only target direct children:

```
$('.#primary-menu > li').mouseenter(function() {
    console.log('please work');
});
```

However, it does not work as it triggers when the submenu items are hovered as well.

I have also seen some examples where the NOT selector is used but I cant get this working either.

```
$('#primary-menu:not(:has(ul.subnav))').mouseenter(function() {
    console.log('please work');
});
```

Can anyone one help?

I have done a very simplistic example here:

https://codepen.io/lol4000/pen/VwMLOMO

//**************UPDATE*************//

I tried the code suggestions by @CertainPerformance but this does not work for my code as I am using wordpress so I cannot add classes to the links.  I tried using the **.menu-item-has-children**  class instead but this does not work.

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').on('mouseenter', () => {
  console.log('top-level item entered');
});
```

Neither does this

```
$('#primary-menu > li').on('mouseenter', (e) => {
  console.log('top-level item entered:' + e.currentTarget.children[0].textContent);
});
```

Actual HTML code below:

```
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-4793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4793"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1-copie.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Faculté</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4908" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4908"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/la-faculte-2/origine-vocation-internationale/">Présentation</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4893" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4893"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/la-faculte-2/origine-vocation-internationale/">Nos atouts</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4892" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4892"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/la-faculte-2/">Devenir des diplômés</a></li>
</ul>
</li>


 <li id="menu-item-4794" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-4794"><a href="/formations/" aria-current="page" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Formations</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
    <li id="menu-item-5049" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-5049"><a href="/formations/" aria-current="page">Formations</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4795" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4795"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/DEPARTEMENTS1.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Départements</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4883" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4883"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/aes-economie-gestion/">AES – Economie-Gestion</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4884" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4884"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/anglais/">Anglais</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4895" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4895"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/droit/">Droit</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4886" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4886"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/pole-international-management/">Pôle International de Management</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4887" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4887"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/langues-orientales/">ILCO</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4888"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/langues-romanes-germaniques/">LRG</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4796" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4796"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1-copie-2.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Vie étudiante</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4833" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4833"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/le-campus/">Le Campus</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4834" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4834"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/la-faculte-2/vie-associative/">Les associations</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4897" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4897"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/le-cadre-de-vos-etudes/">Vivre au Havre</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4797" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4797"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1-copie-4.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Entreprises</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4858" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4858"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/alternance/">Alternance</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4896" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4896"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/entreprises/stages-et-offres-demploi/">Stages</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4898" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4898"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/reprise-detudes/">Formations tout au long de la vie</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4857" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4857"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/taxe-dapprentissage/">Taxe d’apprentissage</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4798" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4798"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1-copie-6.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Recherche</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4859" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4859"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/laboratoires/">Laboratoires</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4905" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4905"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/formations-par-niveaux/doctorat/">Ecoles Doctorales</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4799" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4799"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1-copie-5.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">International</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4861" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4861"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/la-faculte-2/venir-etudier-au-havre/">Venir étudier au Havre</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4862" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4862"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/partir-a-letranger/">Partir à l’étranger</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4866" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4866"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/international-students/">International Students</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4907" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4907"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/international/">Partenaires Internationaux</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4800" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4800"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1-copie-3.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Infos pratiques</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4808" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4808"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/venir-sur-le-campus/">Venir sur le campus</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4903" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4903"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/procedure-dadmission/">Candidater à nos formations</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4870" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4870"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/la-vie-etudiante/services-numeriques/">Outils numériques / Services en ligne</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4871" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4871"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/ma-rentree/">[Ma rentrée]</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4872" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4872"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/quiz-pour-les-indecis/">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think what might happen here is that the mouse enters content of the `li` that the listener is set on which is logical since it's technically entering that `li`. You can add listeners to the `a` with a specific class rather than the `li` that contains everything. What is your end goal here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Logically it's doing what you telling it to do since the sub-menu `li` is still inside of the `li` your listener is set on.

This should fix your issue

```
$('#primary-menu > li > a').on('mouseenter', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the descendant selector, the space - otherwise, all descendants that match the following selector (including nested elements) will have the listener added. Use `>` instead, to select direct children.

The top-level `<ul>` is `#primary-menu`, so use `#primary-menu > li` to select its immediate children.

```js
$('#primary-menu > li').on('mouseenter', (e) => {
  console.log('top-level item entered:' + e.currentTarget.children[0].textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-4793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4793">
    <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1-copie.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Faculté</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-4908" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4908"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/la-faculte-2/origine-vocation-internationale/">Présentation</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4893" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4893"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/la-faculte-2/origine-vocation-internationale/">Nos atouts</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4892" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4892"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/la-faculte-2/">Devenir des diplômés</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-4794" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4794">
    <a href="/formations/" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Formations</span></a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-4795" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4795">
    <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/DEPARTEMENTS1.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Départements</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-4883" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4883"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/aes-economie-gestion/">AES – Economie-Gestion</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4884" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4884"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/anglais/">Anglais</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4895" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4895"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/droit/">Droit</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4886" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4886"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/pole-international-management/">Pôle International de Management</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4887" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4887"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/langues-orientales/">ILCO</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4888"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/langues-romanes-germaniques/">LRG</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-4796" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4796">
    <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1-copie-2.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Vie étudiante</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-4833" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4833"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/le-campus/">Le Campus</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4834" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4834"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/la-faculte-2/vie-associative/">Les associations</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4897" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4897"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/le-cadre-de-vos-etudes/">Vivre au Havre</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-4797" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4797">
    <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1-copie-4.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Entreprises</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-4858" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4858"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/alternance/">Alternance</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4896" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4896"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/entreprises/stages-et-offres-demploi/">Stages</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4898" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4898"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/reprise-detudes/">Formations tout au long de la vie</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4857" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4857"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/taxe-dapprentissage/">Taxe d’apprentissage</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-4798" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4798">
    <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1-copie-6.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Recherche</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-4859" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4859"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/laboratoires/">Laboratoires</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4905" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4905"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/formations/formations-par-niveaux/doctorat/">Ecoles Doctorales</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-4799" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4799">
    <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1-copie-5.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">International</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-4861" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4861"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/la-faculte-2/venir-etudier-au-havre/">Venir étudier au Havre</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4862" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4862"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/partir-a-letranger/">Partir à l’étranger</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4866" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4866"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/international-students/">International Students</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4907" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4907"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/international/">Partenaires Internationaux</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-4800" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4800">
    <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1-copie-3.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Infos pratiques</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-4808" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4808"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/venir-sur-le-campus/">Venir sur le campus</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4903" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4903"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/procedure-dadmission/">Candidater à nos formations</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4870" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4870"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/la-vie-etudiante/services-numeriques/">Outils numériques / Services en ligne</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4871" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4871"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/ma-rentree/">[Ma rentrée]</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4872" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4872"><a href="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/quiz-pour-les-indecis/">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is great, it works with my example. However the real life code is in wordpress and therefore there is no class on the a tag, ie. nav_link and sub_nav_link. So this wont work. Sorry I hadnt noticed this.  I will change the example now.

Comment: Added to the original post, thanks.

Comment: It looks like the issue with `menu-item-has-children` is that some top-level items don't have that class, right? Most do, but `Formations` doesn't.

Comment: Yes thats correct, well spotted. So if I add a submenu and keep it hidden it'll work?  I will try that

Comment: I added a submenu for formations and it still doesnt work

Comment: `#primary-menu` is on top, so it looks like `#primary-menu > li` would work.

Comment: But is doesnt, I tried this previously in wordpress and in the codepen above

Comment: The HTML in your question shows that you have a `#primary-menu`. Does that not actually exist either? If it doesn't, please edit the actual HTML you're working with into your question

Comment: Yes it exists but what you are saying doesnt work... see the codepen